# ValueError: Edit objects may not be used after the TextCommand's run method has returned

Tags: python, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

I am working on porting an existing ST2 plugin to ST3. It's basically a Lorem Ipsum alternative.
https://github.com/cardern/LoremFillerati/blob/master/fillerati.py

Here is the relevant code. I pulled it out of the greater context to only display lines from the trace.

```
class FilleratiCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):

def run(self, edit, n=300, b=None):
    completes = []
    def api_check(thread):
        # Completed.
        completes.append(lambda r, n: self.complete(edit, r, thread.result, n))

def complete(self, edit, region, result, n):
    if region.empty():
        self.view.insert(edit, region.begin(), content)
    else:
        self.view.replace(edit, region, content)
```

When run I get the error in the title. Here is the trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/cardern/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/Fillerati/fillerati.py", line 24, in <lambda>
    sublime.set_timeout(lambda: api_check(thread), 100)
  File "/Users/cardern/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/Fillerati/fillerati.py", line 46, in api_check
    completes[i](region, cnt)
  File "/Users/cardern/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/Fillerati/fillerati.py", line 34, in <lambda>
    lambda r, n: self.complete(edit, r, thread.result, n))
  File "/Users/cardern/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/Fillerati/fillerati.py", line 76, in complete
    self.view.replace(edit, region, content)
  File "/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/MacOS/sublime.py", line 685, in replace
    raise ValueError("Edit objects may not be used after the TextCommand's run method has returned")
ValueError: Edit objects may not be used after the TextCommand's run method has returned
```

It looks to me like this is being caused by disobeying the Restricted begin_edit() and end_edit() section of the porting guide:
https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/porting_guide.html

Does anyone have a suggestion for how to correctly insert the Lorem text to follow ST3's restriction?

Comment: Please post the code—or, better, a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)—in the question, not just a link to an external resource.